# User Creation Fail with sysadminctl

Tags: macos, user-account

I created a user with the `sysadminctl` and faced some errors.
I'm using macOS 10.15.3.

First of all, to create the user I did this:

```
$ sudo sysadminctl -addUser someuser -fullName "Full User Name" -password - -admin
Password:
2020-05-07 10:56:14.958 sysadminctl[48350:60273463] ----------------------------
2020-05-07 10:56:14.958 sysadminctl[48350:60273463] No clear text password or interactive option was specified (adduser, change/reset password will not allow user to use FDE) !
2020-05-07 10:56:14.958 sysadminctl[48350:60273463] ----------------------------
User password:
2020-05-07 10:58:02.965 sysadminctl[48350:60273463] Creating user record…
2020-05-07 10:58:04.044 sysadminctl[48350:60273463] Assigning UID: 504
2020-05-07 10:58:04.056 sysadminctl[48350:60273463] ### Error:-14120 File:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Admin/Admin-803/DSRecord.m Line:418
2020-05-07 10:58:04.162 sysadminctl[48350:60273463] Creating home directory at /Users/someuser
```

Two problems arose as a result:

Problem 1. Error -14120 as you can see in the output above.

Problem 2. A weird directory `/Users/admin` was created:

```
$ ls -la /Users
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   8 root          admin 256 May  7 10:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x  22 root          admin 704 Feb  6 02:08 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root          wheel   0 Nov  9 19:03 .localized
drwxrwxrwt   7 root          wheel 224 Feb  6 02:10 Shared/
drwxr-xr-x+  9 someuser      staff 288 May  7  2019 admin/
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 someuser      staff 352 May  7 10:58 someuser/
drwxr-xr-x+ 17 myaccount     staff 544 May  7  2019 myaccount/
```

What did I do wrong?

Edit:
`/Users/admin/.bash_history` contains `brew doctor`.
Maybe it was in the past used somehow for managing Homebrew.
I still don't understand why sysadminctl updated the timestamps and made the new user the owner of `/Users/admin/`. Perhaps someone in my institute created the user `admin` in the past, and now macOS reused the user ID for me.

I still don't understand the error -14120, though. Maybe the system tried to use an old configuration file from pre-Mojave days.